# py.test: specifying python_files in the command line

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to set the argument `python_files` in pytest. The documentation says you need to put it in a configuration file, but I want to include it in the command line as part of the call to `py.test`, so I won't have to add that configuration file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with pytest out of the box as it is now (2.8). The pytest [parser](https://pytest.org/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.config.Parser) knows about command-line options (`addoption/getoption`) and config file values (`addini/getini`) but they are quite separate.

It is probably possible to write a plugin to add `python_files` (or any other ini value) as a command-line option. But just adding a conftest file is certainly the simpler option.